# How to create a newsletter with a contact list using html, php and tinymce

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I'm trying to create a newsletter which can have a subject header and has a contact list like an address book, which is stored in mySQL. There are three user types and I want to be able to add each type into their own group and when selected their email address goes into the "to" section. I'm just completely lost on how to add these two features in. Anybody have any ideas?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ],
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
```

Then I've got another page with this

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
//-->
</script>

<!-- <IFRAME SRC="usagelogs/default.aspx" id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');"></iframe>-->


<iframe width="100%"  height="600px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" align="middle" seamless="" src="newsletter.php" id="newsletterframe" name="newsletterframe" onLoad="autoResize('newsletterframe');">></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [www.mailchimp.com](http://www.mailchimp.com)? Just wondering.

Comment: Because it's not my site, I'm helping someone with theirs and this is their setup.

Comment: Alright so if you want to accomplish something like this, the most important thing to do is not to write code first. The first thing you should do is create a flow chart for the project and UML diagrams.

Your tables in MySQL should probably be:

Comment: Thanks, it's taking longer than expected but the mailing system is causing a headache and the contact list is working but won't be finished until I've made it look pretty etc, but it's working so that's the main thing. Just ironing the kinks out.